# How to cleanly automate authentication for Azure Devops feeds?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget

Presumably there are lots of companies who are facing the same struggle we are.

For any microservice, before running a `dotnet restore` we need to first ensure we've successfully configured our ADO package feeds with an active token.

To achieve this we have a script which downloads and runs the CredentialProvider.VSS.exe (as suggested by Microsoft), using the output to build credentials which then register the feeds on the user's computer. This needs to happen **daily** as the tokens generated will expire.

The script above is ugly and worse yet, **every** repository needs it in order to ensure feeds are configured with active tokens. Even if we moved the ugly script to a PowerShell module for example, how would we authenticate against the PS feed in order to download that module?

I don't see why the CredentialProvider is neccessary, why can't nuget just prompt us for credentials whenever our token expires? Has anyone come up with a cleaner solution out there which manages authentication to ADO feeds across multiple repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to cleanly automate authentication for Azure Devops feeds?

To authentication for Azure Devops feeds, you could try to use the [NuGet authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget-authenticate?view=azure-devops) task, which configure NuGet tools to authenticate with Azure Artifacts and other NuGet repositories.

[image]

Then we could create a new NuGet service connection with PAT:

[image]

[image]

You can use a longer-term `PAT` for certification, so you don't have to change certification every day.

Answer (score 1):

another approach using nuget.confg as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AzureDevOpsFeed" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget" value="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <VSTSFeed>
       <add key="UserName" value="#{PAT_UserName}#" />      
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="#{PersonalAccessToken}#" />
    </VSTSFeed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```